# How do I tell Mvc to read the web.config in a different views folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, view

I'm working on a pluggable Mvc website. The views for my "plugins" exist in a different folder. The structure looks like this.

```
\website
    \views
        \home
            index.cshtml
        web.config
    \plugins
        \customplugin
            \views
                \home
                    index.cshtml
                web.config
```

So when my controller returns the view I get the error `The view at "XXXX" must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage<TModel>`

I know that I can easily fix this by putting `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage` in my view, but I would like it to use the web.config in the folder instead. Does anyone know how this can be done? Is this something my custom view engine needs to handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found my answer. This is already done for you by .net, however changes to the web.config will not be picked up until you restart your app.

I ended up finding this out by accident. Before I was testing my adding the config file, but you need an app restart for the real magic to happen.

It could also by the custom ControllerFactory too, but I can't verify this at the moment.